# How to debug await functions using Chrome 76?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I want set a breakpoint near `await` function and clicking "step" going into my method

[image]

but, clicking "step" i see this:

[image]

Any trick for skip `__awaiter` and jump to the real method (without set a breakpoint)?

Comment: Compile to ESnext with the tsc

Comment: Try blackboxing tsliv.es6.js by right-clicking inside "Call stack" or in devtools settings https://puu.sh/EfUFL/a4db3761ea.png